# How to perform operations in JMeter with Functions of time

Tags: jmeter

The last for today.
I wanna make a summ of two Functions in JMeter, like:

**${__javaScript((new Date()).toISOString())} + ${__Random(1000,1500)}**

Probably, the STRING is breaking the JMeter execution. This should be a POST method to save in the database something like: ***2024-02-08 17:16:58.130***

But I wanna take the actual time (with the format shown) and summ random number between 1000~1500ms. There is a way to perform this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. StartDateTime: you can use just [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) like:

   ```
   ${__time(yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS,)}
   ```
2. EndDateTime: you will need to go for [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) like:

   ```
   ${__groovy(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(1000\,1500)).format('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS'),)}
   ```